# TS2739: Unable to consume custom Tippy wrapper extending TippyProps in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tippyjs

We maintain two separate repositories as library. Both are using reactjs. One is pure component library while other contains sharable modules.

I started integrating typescript in both these libraries.

Here is Tippy wrapper naming *Tippy.tsx* in component library.

```
import Tooltip, {TippyProps} from '@tippyjs/react'
interface TippyType extends TippyProps {
  hook: string;
  style: Object;
}

const Tippy:React.FC<TippyType> = (props) => {
  const {dataHook = '', style = {}} = props
  function onCreate (instance: any) {
    props?.onCreate?.(instance)
    if (dataHook) {
      instance.props.content.setAttribute('data-hook', dataHook)
    }
    Object.entries(style).forEach(([property, value]) => {
      content.style[property] = value
    })
  }
  return (
    <Tooltip
      { ...props}
      onCreate={onCreate}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
export default Tippy
```

This code builds successfully. But when I try to use this component in module library, typescript  only acknowledges *hook* and *style* props. All other props from tippy PropTypes throw error.

e.g. following code

```
<Tippy
  content={value}
  theme='material'
>
  <span className='inline-block m-r-5 to-ellipsis overflow-hidden ws-nowrap'>{value}</span>
</Tippy>
```

throws

> TS2739: Type '{ children: Element; content: string; theme: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TippyType': hook, 'style'

Here is the declaration file automatically generated *tippy.d.ts*

```
import { TippyProps } from '@tippyjs/react';
import React from 'react';
import './styles.scss';
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
interface TippyType extends TippyProps {
    hook: string;
    'style': Object;
}
declare const Tippy: React.FC<TippyType>;
export default Tippy;
```

Here is [TippyProps](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react/blob/master/index.d.ts#L6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TS2739: Type '{ children: Element; content: string; theme: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TippyType': hook, 'style'

The error is warning you `hook` and `style` are compulsory in Tippy Component.

```js
interface TippyType extends TippyProps {
    hook: string;   // <--- compulsory 
    style: Object;  // <--- compulsory
}
```

Therefore, you need to pass `hook` and `style` when using `Tippy`.

```js
<Tippy
    hook=""
    style={{}}
    content={value}
    theme='material'
>
   <span className='inline-block m-r-5 to-ellipsis overflow-hidden ws-nowrap'>{value}</span>
</Tippy>
```

If you want to mark `hook` and `style` as optional, use `?`:

```js
interface TippyType extends TippyProps {
  hook?: string;
  style?: Object;
}
```